# How to look for specific structural motifs in proteins?

Tags: proteins

Is there a way to search to search for specific structural motifs in proteins?
For example can a database where we can find structures with zing finger motif or an hairpin...

PDBeMotif (ebi.ac.uk) has some motifs for example but no way to download them.
Small Three-Dimensional Protein Motifs (gla.ac.uk) also offers some.

Comment: Do you have a sequence of amino acids for making the search?

Comment: yeah for some motif, but not all of them. They are not sequence dependent, just make similar structural fold.

Comment: for some motifs then you can use that sequence and run it through `blast` to get other crystal structures where your search sequence is conserved.  Even though they are not sequence dependent, It is highly likely there is a pattern (in your known sequence) of amino acids which can make the fold. Did you try `Zif-BASE`

Comment: @Vasista Do you think you could expand that into an answer? This question has remained in the unanswered queue for almost 3 months now!

Comment: It seems that @Vasista asked you in their last comment, about whether or not you tried `Zif-BASE`. I think without at an answer to that comment, your chances of getting an answer from Vasista would be lower than if you did answer the comment. Have you had a chance to try it yet?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.